# Error: Cannot use GraphQLObjectType "Query" from another module or realm

Tags: strapi

I am setting up Strapi on windows. When I run `npx create-strapi-app my-project`<select template "blog" the following error appears:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSbw7.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to reinstall `strapi-plugin-graphql` and `graphql`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).